# induction integer record in coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The definition of int comes from compcert,

```
Record int: Type := mkint { intval: Z; intrange: -1 < intval < modulus }.
```

I wanna prove foo, suppose that the induction strategy needs to be used, because there is a recursive relationship in P1 and P2, and i is positive in P1 and P2 actually.

```
From compcert Require Import Integers.

Parameter P1 : int -> Prop.
Parameter P2 : int -> Prop.

Theorem foo: 
    forall i: int,
    (P1 i) -> (P2 i).
Proof.
    destruct i. induction intval.
    admit.
    induction p.
Abort.
```

If induction p, I need to prove two cases, BinNums.Zpos (BinNums.xI p) and BinNums.Zpos (BinNums.xO p). it is hard to prove, I would like to be able to use int like nat, that is something to prove P1 (i + 1) -> P2 (i + 1) by (P1 i) -> (P2 i)

Any hints? thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you are using `int` numbers from CompCert makes everything more complicated, because there is too little arithmetic available for this datatype.

If you were using just plain integers of type `Z`, you would be able to perform the proof you require by using `well_founded_induction` and `Zwf.Zwf_well_founded`.  Here is an example.

```
Theorem foo: 
    forall i: Z, (0 <= i)%Z -> P i.
intros i.
induction i using 
  (well_founded_ind (Zwf.Zwf_well_founded 0)).
Print Zwf.
intros ige0.
assert (cases : (i = 0 \/ 0 < i)%Z) by lia.
destruct cases as [case0 | casegt0].
  rewrite case0.
  now apply base_case.
assert (dec : i = ((i - 1) + 1)%Z) by lia.
rewrite dec.
apply rec_case.
apply H.
  unfold Zwf.
  lia.
lia.
Qed.
```

Now, if we want to make a similar proof using numbers of type `int`, life is more complicated because these numbers are in a record, and this record contains a field that is a proof.  Usually, the value of the proof is irrelevant, only its existence matters, in in this case we would rather have the `intval` projection be injective.  To make it short, I simply place myself in a theoretical setting where this is granted, this well known and acceptable in most use cases.  Here is the full example:

```
Require Import ZArith Zwf.
Require Import Wellfounded.
Require Import Lia.
Require Import ProofIrrelevance.

Open Scope Z_scope.

Parameter modulus : Z.

Hypothesis modulus_gt_0 : 0 < modulus.

Record int : Type := mkint {intval : Z; intrange: -1 < intval < modulus}.

Lemma intval_inj : forall x y : int, intval x = intval y -> x = y.
Proof.
intros [x xp] [y yp]; simpl. 
intros xy; revert xp; rewrite xy; intros xp.
now rewrite (proof_irrelevance _ xp yp).
Qed.

Definition int0 := mkint 0 (conj eq_refl modulus_gt_0).

Parameter P : int -> Prop.

Axiom base_case : P int0.

Lemma modulo_Z_bound (z : Z) : -1 < z mod modulus < modulus.  
Proof.
assert (tmp := Z.mod_pos_bound z modulus modulus_gt_0).
lia.
Qed.

Axiom rec_case : forall x, P x -> P (mkint _ (modulo_Z_bound (intval x + 1))).

Theorem foo: forall i, P i.
intros i; destruct i as [z zbounds].
revert zbounds.
induction z as [z Ih] using (well_founded_ind (Zwf_well_founded 0)).
intros zbounds.
assert (cases : z = 0 \/ 0 < z) by lia.
destruct cases as [case0 | casegt0].
  revert zbounds; rewrite case0.
  intros zbounds; assert (isint0 : {|intval := 0; intrange := zbounds|} = int0).
    now apply intval_inj; simpl.
  now rewrite isint0; apply base_case.
assert (zm1_bounds : -1 < z - 1 < modulus) by lia.
assert (dec : {| intval := z; intrange := zbounds|} =
        mkint _ (modulo_Z_bound (intval (mkint _ zm1_bounds) + 1))).
  apply intval_inj; simpl.
  replace (z - 1 + 1) with z by ring.
  symmetry; apply Z.mod_small; lia.
rewrite dec.
apply rec_case.
apply Ih.
unfold Zwf.
lia.
Qed.
```

Note that `mkint _ (modulo_Z_bound (intval x + 1))` is just a way to write `x + 1` when `x` has type `int`  (with the convention that
the successor of the largest number is 0).

There is a way to avoid using the `proof_irrelevance` axiom, but this would make this answer even longer.